# Compare parameters of multiple callbacks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback

I am programming a game using the Unity Engine and I am currently running into the following problem:

I have a method that asynchronously returns his result using the parameters of a callback function. Pretty straightforward, it looks like this:

```
public void CalculateSomething( - PARAMETERS - , Action<float> callback)
```

I have to call this method in a loop for different parameters.

```
foreach(float f in manyFloats){
    CalculateSomething(f, myCallback);
}
void myCallback(float f){
    ...compare this result value to the other values?...
}
```

Now I would like to compare the resulting floats, that come with the different callbacks. Let's just say I want to find the highest value among those floats. How do I do that?

I had the idea to store the results in an array field and just compare after it is fully filled, but I don't know how to check if all callbacks are done already.

Ideally I'd like to avoid polluting my class with a field like this, but it would be alright if there is no other way.

The `CalculateSomething`function is part of a library, so I can't change it. Everything else is variable.

Comment: do you need the callback setup you have now?  With that sample code, it seems easiest to return a value from `CalculateSomething` to add to a list, and you can compare values after the loop.

Comment: The `CalculateSomething` is from a different library, so this has to stay. Everything else could be changed.
About your suggestion:
How do I know when the list is filled? How do I check if every callback has finished already? Could I do this without polluting my class?

Edit: Whoops, that wasn't meant to be sent already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the deal.
You got it right about creating the array and storing the values and compare them when all callbacks are done. Hence the problem is that you don't know when all the callbacks are returned. But you know how many callbacks are there based on count of your origin `manyFloats` variable. All you need to do is keep a counter and add it up every time a callback is returned. And check if it equals the count of manyFloats then you can do the comparison:

```
int count = 0;
void myCallback(float f)
{
    ... usual stuff
    ... then
    if(count == manyFloats.Count) 
    {
        // do the comparison
    }
    else
    {
        count ++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a callback based model you should use a `Task` based model.  Have `CalculateSomething` return a `Task<float>` instead of having a callback.  This allows you to use the TPL to compose these `Task` objects by writing code like:

```
var highestResult = (await Task.WhenAll(manyFloats.Select(CalculateSomething))).Max();
```

If you can't edit the method itself, then create your own wrapper that transforms the method into a task based version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I do that without changing `CalculateSomething`? The thing is that it is part of a library.

Comment: @MaXL130 I addressed that in my last sentence.

Comment: Yes you did...sry for missing that. So I guess I will start learning more about tasks and how to use them.

Comment: I don't think that you can use await/async stuff in Unity3D as it uses .net 2.0

Comment: @UmairM There's a library to access TPL features on older version of .NET that you can install.

Answer (score 0):

So, if we have no control over CalculateSomething function, we still can store max value and make comparison in our callback. Something like this:

```
void callbackFunction( float numb){
    if (numb > maxNumb) //maxNumb is global
        maxNumb = numb;
}
```

then you can use your foreach loop to go through your array. Just keep in mind that you would need to declare your maxValue global variable and make it initially equal to minimum value.

Even if you are not doing Min/Max comparison, and it is something more complicated, you still can do it in callback function. No need for arrays, because even with arrays if you can do it with single pass through array - you can do it in a callback function.

Comment: I am not able to change the `CalculateSomething` function, since it is part of a library. So I guess that wouldn't work?

Comment: This suffers from all of [these problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836595/compare-parameters-of-multiple-callbacks-in-c-sharp#comment66963122_39836595) that the OP has mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: I have updated my answer considering everything mentioned above. I still believe it is better way, than storing everything in array and than doing literally the same.

Comment: With your current answer I'd eventually get the biggest value in maxNumb, but I still wouldn't know when the last callback had finished, don't I?

Comment: Well, you can use Count part from Umair's answer if you need to handle the moment when you process last float from manyFloats array. I can update my answer if it helps you.

Comment: That's not necessary, I already got it working. But thanks for your help anyways!